# Dead Centered Div

Tags: javascript, css

How is it possible to center a div both horizontally and vertically with respect to the screen, not the page. So that when the user scrolls down a long page, the div remains horizontally and vertically centered?

Comment: what do you mean vertically centered while scrolling? to do horizontal centering use `margin: 0px auto;`

Comment: just exactly in the center of the screen, even when the user is scrolling down a 5000px long page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS solution, note the percentages and negative margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/R7Xy2/

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice clean solution. Just wanted to add that this will work when the div you're centering is the direct child of the body element, or there are no 'positioned' ancestors between the div and the body element.

Comment: Anyone know which browsers this has been tested in?  The jsfiddle link isn't working for me...

Answer (score 0):

CSS for the `<div>`:

```
position: absolute
left : (centerofpagepixel.x - (width of div /2));
top : (centerofpagepixel.y - (height of div/2));
```

Set the above using jQuery on the `<div>`.

You can calculate the `centerofpagepixel.x` and `y` using jQuery again. Probably get the width/height of the screen and divide them by 2.

Comment: just appending, the key here is position: absolute css style.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try the following:

HTML markup:

```
<div class="classname">text here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.classname {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

The border and padding can be changed or removed on the basis of requirement. Also, make sure that the parent container must be positioned relatively, i.e. it should have `position:relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

**http://www.geekdaily.net/2007/07/04/javascript-cross-browser-window-size-and-centering/**

just attach this event to window.onscroll. No need to use jQuery, try this

```
function addEvent(obj,ev,fn) {
  if(obj.addEventListener) obj.addEventListener(ev,fn,false);
  else if(obj.attachEvent) obj.attachEvent("on"+ev,fn);
}

addEvent(window,"scroll",yourfunction);
```

good luck